# CAD software for 3D printing

Tags: 3d, cad

I would like to learn how to design 3D objects for the use of 3D printing in manufacturing.

So what is the best CAD software for this purpose?

I use windows OS. And I have ni price limit.

I have no experience in CAD, I'm a beginner.

Thank you.

Comment: is your budget actually unlimited (CAD can be very expensive)? how much experience do you have with CAD? please [edit](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/79579/edit) your original question accordingly

Comment: I will work at university, that's why I said that I have no limit on price. Because I think the university is supposed to have all useful softwares. I will edit the question.

Comment: Why is my level of experience important for choosing the software?

Comment: some more advanced software may seem convoluted for a beginner. You may also need to change configs and install plugins for some uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Creo

I personally use [PTC Creo](https://www.ptc.com/en/products/creo/) (formerly Pro Engineer) for Uni.
It is quite capable and widely used in both education and industry.

I has many features and a fairly nice GUI. However I feel like some introduction to this software may be needed if you never used CAD before.
For this please ask at your University/Company or watch some of the [official tutorials](https://www.ptc.com/en/ptc-university).

Creo is available both in a parametric and direct modelling version.

### Siemens NX

I have only worked a little with [NX](https://www.plm.automation.siemens.com/global/en/products/nx/) but most of the big commercial CAD softwares are somewhat similar, so I would simply go with your employers recommendation.

### Solidworks

[Solidworks](https://www.solidworks.com/) I would consider a simpler CAD. This will easily suffice for simpler work and might be a great choice for a beginner.

### FreeCAD

[FreeCAD](https://www.freecadweb.org/) is Free and Open source. It has a lot of features but in my opinion it is not as easy to use as Creo and NX. I would recommend this for low cost or low level CAD work. It also integrates many different styles of CAD into one (openSCAD e.g.).